# PHP reading JSON post from Unity C# issue

Tags: c#, php, json, unity-game-engine

We are trying to send simple JSON to local php runing on XAMP and save data to MySql, we tried many different codes we think Unity C# code is true but we are not sure, we tested many different PHP codes but half codes show nothing half show some error, i post both last used codes, any suggest welcome.

C# Unity:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text;


public class JSON : MonoBehaviour 
{


IEnumerator Start() 
{
Debug.Log ("Posting JSON...");

string URL = "http://localhost/php/page.php";

WWWForm form = new WWWForm ();
form.AddField ("username", "testuser");
form.AddField ("password", "testpass");

var headers = form.headers;
headers["content-type"] = "application/json";

WWW www = new WWW(URL, form.data, headers);

yield return www;
Debug.Log (www.uploadProgress);

if (www.error == null)
 {
    Debug.Log("WWW Ok!: " + www.text);
 } else {
    Debug.Log("WWW Error: "+ www.error);
 }    

  }

}
```

PHP XAMP:

```
<?php


$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "localdb");

$filename = file_get_contents('php://input');

$data = file_get_contents($filename);

$array = json_decode($data, true);

foreach ($array as $row)
{
$sql = "INSERT INTO localtable (username, password)   VALUES('".$row[username]."','".$row[password]."')";       
mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
}

echo $data;

?>
```

Unity Log:

> WWW Ok!: 
>  **Warning**: 
>   file_get_contents(username=testuser&password=testpass): failed to
>   open stream: No such file or directory in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\php\page.php** on line **8**
>  
>   **Warning**:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\php\page.php** on line **12**
>  JSON data
>   added. UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object) c__Iterator3:MoveNext()
>   (at Assets/Scripts/JSON.cs:31)
>   UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext(IEnumerator, IntPtr)

PHP error:

> Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\php\page.php on line 8
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\php\page.php on line 12 JSON data added.

Edit 1: No error, No data.

```
<?php
 $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
 print_r($data);
 echo $data["username"];
 echo $data["password"];
?>
```

Edit 2:

```
 <?php
   $data = file_get_contents('php://input');// $data == "username=testuser&password=testpass"
   parse_str($data, $result);
   echo $result["username"]; // "testuser"
   echo "   ";
   echo $result["password"]; // "testpass"
   echo "   ";
?>
```

> Unity show data: testuser   testpass
>
> PHP show:
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\page.php
>   on line 5
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\page.php
>   on line 7

Edit 3: Final PHP code not add any record to Mysql

```
    <?php
   $data = file_get_contents('php://input');// $data == "username=testuser&password=testpass"
   parse_str($data, $result);
   echo $result["username"]; // "testuser"
   echo "   ";
   echo $result["password"]; // "testpass"
   echo "   ";

   $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","admin","123456", "localdb");
   $array = json_decode($data, true);

   $sql = "INSERT INTO localtable (username, password)   VALUES('".$result["password"]."','".$result["password"]."')";       
   mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

   echo "   ";

   echo $queryResult = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);//Return 1
?>
```

Comment: What's the error you got?

Comment: in Mysql empty records added.

Comment: What is the value `mysqli_query` returned?

Comment: where i must check it? in PHP page nothing show.

Comment: `$queryResult = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);`

Comment: echo $queryResult = mysqli_query($connect, $sql); show 1 on PHP page.

Comment: That's not an error. Use `isset` to remove that if you care.

Comment: 1 means true. So the query should succeed... not add any record to Mysql? really?

Comment: I checked again not added.

Comment: Is all PHP and SQL query codes true?

Comment: Yes.. I can't find anything wrong any more.

Comment: I changed database user with another username and password, nothing changed

Comment: When i changed table name to a wrong name PHP not show that 1 value, it seems code is true but i don't know where is problem.

Comment: I restarted XAMP and tested again, not any record add.

Comment: Try using the `mysqli_prepare` method. Maybe some security settings in mysql forbid the way you adding the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$filename = file_get_contents('php://input');

$data = file_get_contents($filename);
```

`$filename` is the form data you got from the Unity3D client. That's not a file path and also not a JSON string. That is just a string. You are **not** sending a json.

See the log, it is

```
username=testuser&password=testpass
```

Use [`parse_str`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php#refsect1-function.parse-str-examples) to get the username and password.

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "localdb");
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');// $data == "username=testuser&password=testpass"
$result = null;
parse_str($data, $result);    
echo $result["username"]; // "testuser"
echo $result["password"]; // "testpass"

if ($stmt = $mysqli_prepare("INSERT INTO localtable (username, password) VALUES(?,?)")) {
    /* bind parameters for markers */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "username", $result["username"]);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "password", $result["password"]);

    /* execute query */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    /* close statement */
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}

?>
```

Comment: i have zero knowledge of php, i really don't know what must i do. i hope some developers here could help.

Comment: where i must put them? and how to use them? tutorial link couldn't help me.

Comment: Ok after get 15 reputation i'll do it.